# Enable HTTP/2 instead of http/1.1 on local server

Tags: apache, http2

I'm trying to use http/2 on my website instead of http/1.1 which is already obsolete.
I've already followed some tutorials but I'm not having success. I'll explain what I did.

I changed the following file vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>

            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            ServerName gestao.centro.local
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            SSLEngine on
            SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2

            SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/gestaocentrolocal3.cer
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/gestaocentrolocal2.key
            SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/centro64.cer

            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>
            Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1

    </VirtualHost>
```

Where I added the following lines:

`SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2 Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1`

When I execute the following line `curl --http2 https://gestao.centro.local -I` I get the following result:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Mon, 26 Feb 2024 12:16:41 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Upgrade: h2,h2c Connection: Upgrade Last-Modified: Fri, 24 Nov 2023 10:54:06 GMT ETag: "8d5-60ae3c573e0d0" Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Length: 2261 Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Type: text/html`

Still not using HTTP/2 but HTTP/1.1.

If I execute this line `curl -I -v --tlsv1.2 --tls-max 1.2 https://gestao.centro.local` I get the following result:

`Trying 192.168.0.22:443...

- TCP_NODELAY set
- Connected to gestao.centro.local (192.168.0.22) port 443 (#0)
- ALPN, offering h2
- ALPN, offering http/1.1
- successfully set certificate verify locations:
- CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
- SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
- ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
- Server certificate:
- subject: C=PT
- start date: Apr  1 13:31:18 2022 GMT
- expire date: Mar 31 13:31:18 2024 GMT
- subjectAltName: host "gestao.centro.local" matched cert's "gestao.centro.local"
- issuer: DC=local; DC=centro; CN=rad
- SSL certificate verify ok.

> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> Host: gestao.centro.local
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*

- Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
  < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  < Date: Mon, 26 Feb 2024 12:17:40 GMT
  Date: Mon, 26 Feb 2024 12:17:40 GMT
  < Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
  Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
  < Upgrade: h2,h2c
  Upgrade: h2,h2c
  < Connection: Upgrade
  Connection: Upgrade
  < Last-Modified: Fri, 24 Nov 2023 10:54:06 GMT
  Last-Modified: Fri, 24 Nov 2023 10:54:06 GMT
  < ETag: "8d5-60ae3c573e0d0"
  ETag: "8d5-60ae3c573e0d0"
  < Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  < Content-Length: 2261
  Content-Length: 2261
  < Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  < Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Type: text/html
- Connection #0 to host gestao.centro.local left intact
  `

I can't understand if I already have HTTP/2 configured correctly and my website already uses it or if I still need some steps to use it.

When I do a Lighthouse report in the Google Chrome console I receive this information:

```
Use HTTP/2 27 requests not served via HTTP/2
```